# How to change source for a custom rails generator? (Thor)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, generator, thor

I'm making a custom generator that generates a new rails app, and I do it like this

```
require 'thor'
require 'rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator'

class AppBuilder < Rails::AppBuilder
  include Thor::Actions
  include Thor::Shell
  ...
end
```

The problem is, how do I add a new source directory (which is then used by `Thor::Actions#copy_file`, `Thor::Actions#template`, and the others)? I saw in the Thor's documentation that `Thor::Actions#source_paths` holds the sources (it's an array of paths), so I tried overriding it inside my class (since I've included `Thor::Actions`):

```
def source_paths
  [File.join(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)), "templates")] + super
end
```

With this I wanted to add the `./templates` directory in the sources, while still keeping the Rails' one (that's why the `+ super` at the end). But it doesn't work, it still lists the Rails' source path as the only one.

I tried browsing through the Rails' source code, but I couldn't find how Rails put **his** directory in the source paths. And I really want to know that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked:

```
require 'thor'
require 'rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator'

module Thor::Actions
  def source_paths
    [MY_TEMPLATES]
  end
end

class AppBuilder < Rails::AppBuilder
  ...
end
```

I don't understand why, but I've spent too much time on this already, so I don't care.

Answer (score 5):

Thor will access your source_paths method and add these to the defaults:

```
  # Returns the source paths in the following order:
  #
  #   1) This class source paths
  #   2) Source root
  #   3) Parents source paths
  #
  def source_paths_for_search
    paths = []
    paths += self.source_paths
    paths << self.source_root if self.source_root
    paths += from_superclass(:source_paths, [])
    paths
  end
```

So all you need to do in your class is:

```
class NewgemGenerator < Thor::Group

  include Thor::Actions

  def source_paths
    ['/whatever', './templates']
  end

end
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I've tried that, I still get this error: `Could not find "<any_file>" in any of your source paths. Your current source paths are: path/to/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates`, so it didn't pick it up at all.

Comment: I added the class definition and include I was using to my answer.

Comment: But I have to subclass `Rails::AppBuilder`, because I'm overriding what that class generates.

Comment: I'll award you the bounty, so it doesn't go to waste.

Comment: Thanks! Good luck with your project.

Comment: I think that `source_path` method should be wrapped inside `no_tasks` block to prevent generating exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

The source_paths method doesn't work when using AppBuilder. (which is another option to using rails templates). I have a files directory next to the app_builder.rb file that this class is in. I have this working, though it seems there should still be a more elegant way.

```bsh
tree .
|-- app_builder.rb
|-- files
     `-- Gemfile
```

```rb
class AppBuilder < Rails::AppBuilder

  def initialize generator
    super generator
    path = File.expand_path( File.join( '..', File.dirname( __FILE__ )) )
    source_paths << path
  end

  def gemfile
    copy_file 'files/Gemfile', 'Gemfile'
  end
```

and then on the console:

`rails new my_app -b path_to_app_builder.rb`

The dots are required since the ruby file 'app_builder.rb' is slurped up and eval'd after the `rails new` command changes into the new app directory (I think).

Answer (score 1):

It's an old post, however, the problem remains the same, I spent time to figure that out. I let a comment here if it can help.

Rails add by default the path `lib/templates` so you can custom any templates by copying them in this directory.

Check out the correct directories structures https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/v6.0.1/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails

There is subtle though and is not so obvious to catch.

Take for instance the `helper` generator, as mentioned in the official Rails documentation, the structure is

https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/v6.0.1/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/helper

```
- helper
  - templates
    - helper.rb.tt
  - helper_generator.rb
```

Here, what `Railties` expects to find in your project:

```
- lib
  - templates 
    - helper
      - helper.rb
```

your `helper.rb` is a copy of `helper.rb.tt`

the last thing, if you plan to use it in `Rails::Engine` you have to tell it to load that path

```
# lib/blorgh/engine.rb 
module Blorgh
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Blorgh
    config.generators.templates << File.expand_path('../templates', __dir__)
  end
end
```

Really hope that can help and save time for others.

1. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.1/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L188
2. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow-by-changing-generators-templates
3. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.1/railties/CHANGELOG.md
4. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html