# Adding source paths to generator (thor, rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thor

Trying to make my own app generator (i.e. `rails new appName -m path/to/generator`) and use my custom generator alongside the rails one.

All goes well except when I want to add a source_path. There are several posts about how this could work with generators for existing apps - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879891/how-to-change-source-for-a-custom-rails-generator-thor) and I get the same error.

When I add the following line to the top of my script:

source_root File.expand_path('../dependencies',**FILE**)

the console returns:
 `apply': undefined method 'source_root' for # Rails::Generators:: App Generator : 0x007f8b0a2a3798> (NoMethodError)`

how should I restructure my generator given I am in a Rails project and not a pure ruby one?