# Override Rails scaffold generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The scaffold generator in rails generates the MVC layers from the templates located in `lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/templates` railties path and from the `lib/templates` folder in your project.

If you copy the original files from the railties folder to your projects lib folder, then you'll be able to customize the original `scaffold` generator, as Daniel Fone explain in his [blog](http://daniel.fone.net.nz/blog/2014/02/01/customising-scaffold-views-in-ruby-on-rails/).

The original Rails generator uses 5 files in the views layer:

- `_form.html.erb`
- `edit.html.erb`
- `index.html.erb`
- `new.html.erb`
- `show.html.erb`

I was wondering if the there is a way to extend this behavior by adding another file to the set. like `_header.html.erb` or `_info.html.erb` (some partials that I've design).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well after a couple months I've found the solution. Instead of creating a new generator as the Rails [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow-by-changing-generators-templates) states, I override the default generator but in my projects `lib` folder.

[image]

The original `scaffold_generator.rb` is located at `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold`. To add the new file (`_info.html.erb`) we will add it to the `available_views` method.

```
def available_views
    %w(index edit show new _form _info)
end
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Mmm.. well I haven't had the chance to use this with `slim`... I'm not even sure if slim is currently full compatible with Rails 5... but I'm sure that those templates (located at `rails/generators/erb/scaffold`) are not for slim, so the templates you're looking for should be in the slim gem, not in rails gem. Please look in that folder for methods like `avaiable_views` or `index edit..` strings, I believe it should not be that hard to find. Let me know how it goes ;)

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59161774/552320

Answer (score 8):

For those who are lazy, here is a quick command to copy the default railties erb templates to the correct location in Rails:

```
mkdir -p lib/templates/erb/scaffold && \
cp $(bundle info railties --path)/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/templates/* lib/templates/erb/scaffold
```

Comment: To bring this answer up to date:
mkdir -p lib/templates/erb/scaffold && cp $(bundle info railties | grep Path: | cut -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)//lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/templates/* lib/templates/erb/scaffold

Comment: @DaveBenson cheers, updated - but used `bundle info railties --path` instead of grep and cut.