# Overriding Rails Scaffold for Custom API Versioning Functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, generator, ruby-on-rails-5, scaffolding

I'm trying to customize the rails scaffold command so that when I run

```
rails generate scaffold api/v1/model_name
```

it still produces the folder structure but doesn't add api_v1_ to the views, tests, etc.

i.e.
[image]

I understand how to override and add new partials from this post:
[Override Rails scaffold generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384713/override-rails-scaffold-generator) but I would like to override the test, factory, and view.