# Rails 5.2.0 - scaffold `form_with` includes `local: true` by default

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-5

When I scaffold a Rails 5.2.0 app, my scaffolded forms are always generated with the `local: true` option included in `form_with`.

`rails g scaffold Article title:string`

#### Generated scaffold form

```
<%= form_with(model: article, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% article.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

#### Generated HTML

```
<form action="/articles/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
```

Note the lack of `data-remote` attribute

#### Documentation

I thought the default for `form_with` in Rails 5.1.2+ was to use remote AJAX / xhr requests with `data-remote` attributes? In other words, NOT include the `local: true` option.

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with

> By default form_with attaches the data-remote attribute submitting the form via an XMLHTTPRequest in the background if an Unobtrusive JavaScript driver, like rails-ujs, is used. See the :local option for more.

Note - `rails-ujs`gem was moved into Rails itself in 5.2.0 - https://github.com/rails/rails-ujs. So it looks like I should not need to add anything to the gemfile to enable the default `form_with` behavior.

#### Troubleshooting

I do use a `.railsrc` and a rails template file to customize my `rails new` scaffolds. However, I have tried disabling & removing both files and still get same results from new scaffolded apps.

Comment: `form_with` includes by default `remote:true`. You can add `remote: false` if you don't want to make your request via JS. Also, `form_with` is the 'new' rails way to work with forms.

Comment: Thanks for help @Horacio. But this question was for forms generated by scaffolds, not manually. I found out that the template used for scaffolded forms explicitly uses the `local: true` option on `form_with` (see below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give a more complete answer based on my comment, here's how to add a template to customize the form partial generated by Rails when using the scaffold generator. I'm assuming here that you're using ERB, but the procedure is similar if you're using something like slim-rails to customize your view generators.

Create a file in your Rails project: `lib/templates/erb/scaffold/_form.html.erb.tt`

For this new file's content, a good place to start from is the content in the existing template. You can use `gem which rails` to locate the file that defines Rails in your current environment (with a result like `/home/<user>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@<gemset>/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails.rb`), and from there you can find the form template in `railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/templates/_form.html.erb.tt`. Copy the contents of that file into your new generator template.

Try making some changes to the new template file, and then run the rails scaffold generator (`rails g scaffold foo ...`). You should see your changes reflected in the `_form.html.erb` file created by the generator.

Bear in mind that this template is 'doubly nested' ERB, meaning that it is processed with ERB a first time to produce a view partial, and then processed again every time your Rails app serves a request with it. That said, it's usually not too mind-melting to make a simple change, such as removing `local: true` from your new template

In depth info on customizing Rails generators is available at [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow-by-changing-generators-templates).

Comment: Nice! Thanks @Pathogen !  Great walk-thru. That’s what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Think I found answer - and it's simple :) - the Rails scaffold templates for 5.2.0 explicitly include the `local: true` option.

#### 5.2.0 Template for forms

```
<%%= form_with(model: <%= model_resource_name %>, local: true) do |form| %>
```

So I guess they wanted `local: true` as the default template for scaffolds. Probably for simplicity?

#### To find the scaffold generator templates

Thanks to this post for helping find the source: [Override Rails scaffold generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384713/override-rails-scaffold-generator)

- Find where your gems live with `gem enviornment` command
- I use rbenv, so mine are at `~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems`
- `cd` into that file and look for `railties-5.2.0`
- search in `rails/generators/scaffold/templates`, or just search for `local: true`
- here's the path: `~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/templates/_form.html.erb.tt`

Comment: I'd recommend against hacking your local Rails gems to customize your templates! These changes won't be checked into source control, won't be available to collaborators and will disappear if you ever lose or upgrade your local gems.


Rails has a feature for customizing scaffold templates, do take a look: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow-by-changing-generators-templates